# What is the gmp_nextprime algorithm?

Tags: php, gmp

I am relearning a lot of PHP currently and I have come across gmp.

I know that gmp can be added to PHP, but what if you cant?

The usual prime listing method involves:

```
$max = 10;
for( $prime = 2; $prime <= $max; $prime++ ) {
    for( $count = 2; $count < $prime; $count++ ) {
        if( $prime % $count == 0 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if( $count == $prime )
        echo "Prime: ", $prime, "<br>";
    }
}
```

It is very slow when reaching over thousands.

For gmp it only takes a couple of milliseconds.

What is its algorithm?

How does it find the next prime number?

Comment: Dont forget its compiled so its running in C which is faster.. https://fossies.org/dox/gmp-6.1.2/nextprime_8c_source.html

Comment: I did not know it was compiled.  Is this the only function in PHP that can work with primes?

Comment: Try this, its faster in my tests against yours. https://3v4l.org/UNRqS

Comment: Slightly better version which suits your parameters, https://3v4l.org/5Jp5F

Comment: @LawrenceCherone your second link does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link. http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-nextprime.php

> This function uses a probabilistic algorithm to identify primes and
>   chances to get a composite number are extremely small.

This quote comes from the link. The link specifies that the function uses probabilistic algorithm. The algorithm may end up getting composite number. But, the chances are extremely small.

There is also a good article about probabilistic algorithm.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X80900840

Comment: The last link mathematics hurts my head.  I will research more on this.